# JavaScript and Python bitwise OR operation gave different results

Tags: javascript, python, numbers, bitwise-or

JS

```js
console.log(1 | 1); // 1
console.log(1 | 0x8); // 9
console.log(1 | 0x80000000); // -2147483647
```

python

```py
print (1 | 1) # 1
print (1 | 0x8) # 9
print (1 | 0x80000000) # 2147483649
```

Why the results in last examples are different?

Comment: Python numbers are not the same as JavaScript numbers.

Comment: Python has infinite precision integers, JavaScript integers are 32-bit signed.

Comment: @Barmar I thought JS didn't even really have an integer data type really, and that all numbers are floating point underneath the hood.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The bitwise operators use 32-bit signed numbers internally.

Comment: @Barmar good to know, that makes sense

Comment: It's a little weird -- they should probably use 32-bit unsigned, IMHO. But I guess the designers had their reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tha JavaScript behavior is described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format, except for zero-fill right shift which results in an unsigned 32-bit integer.

So you get negative numbers in JavaScript because it treats the value as a 32-bit signed number. The `0x80000000` bit is the sign bit.

The qualifier at the end of the above quote points the way to get the same result as Python:

```js
console.log((1 | 0x80000000) >>> 0);
```

`>>>` is the zero-fill right shift operator. Shifting by 0 bits doesn't change the value, but it gets converted to unsigned.

Python integers have infinite precision, so they don't wrap around to negative numbers when they get to 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I can't get rid of the feeling that bitwise representation in JS is buggy. For example, it's well known that << operator multiplies a number by two. It works like a charm in python, but breaks in JS for examples like 0x40000000 << 1

Comment: You get the same result in C if you make the mistake of using signed int.